# MySQL timestamp fields - created/modified

Tags: mysql

I have recently decided to stop using MySQL triggers for my `created` and `modified` date fields in my tables due to complications when running scripts included in the setup file on client deployment.

I have altered the fields this way: (example)

```
alter table users 
modify `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

alter table users 
modify `modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
        ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When I now run my program and fill in a form to add data (form controls are databound), I get the message "Column 'created' does not allows nulls".

On already existing data, when I try to update, the modified date simply doesnt change.

I have looked at many articles such as [Having both a Created and Last Updated timestamp columns in MySQL 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267658/having-both-a-created-and-last-updated-timestamp-columns-in-mysql-4-0) but cannot find a solution.

How do I solve this?

I am using MySQL v 5.6.15.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the driver, the 0000-00-00 date might be treated as null, which isn't valid for your column definition. But if that wasn't the case, **any date prior to 1970** isn't a valid timestamp either.

I'd try defining "created" as DATETIME instead of TIMESTAMP

```
alter table users modify `created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

(That is the lowest date a DATETIME can take). As to why the modified column is not working, it's part of the same problem. Tables are supposed to have **only one timestamp column**, but if you put two or more, only the first one can have CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Silly mysql limitations.

This restriction will be lifted in future version, but I guess yours hasn't that yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The version I am using is the latest for Visual Studio development. I have altered the created field as you stated. Unfortunately, I am still experiencing the same problems. Could it be the c# datasets I am using?

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE 'my_table'
CHANGE `created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0,
CHANGE `modified` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

But be sure to give any value to created and modified during create and update operations.

Here is an example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE ts_test5 (
-> created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0,
-> updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
-> data CHAR(30)
-> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO ts_test5 (created, data)
-> VALUES (NULL, ‘original_value’);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM ts_test5;
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| created             |updated              |data            |   
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 2005-01-04 14:47:39 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | original_value |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> . . . time passes . . .

mysql> UPDATE ts_test5 SET data=’updated_value’;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1
Changed: 1
Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM ts_test5;
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| created             |updated              |data           |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| 2005-01-04 14:47:39 | 2005-01-04 14:47:52 | updated_value |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using datasets to add/update my data, no made queries. E.g this.usersTableAdapter.Update(this.payrollDataSet.users);
this.payrollDataSet.users.AcceptChanges();

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
alter table users modify 
   `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

To:

```
alter table users modify 
   `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
```

Or:

```
alter table users modify 
   `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
```