# Hive equivalent of Teradata statement

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to convert a Teradata query to Hive

```
WHERE visit_date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE-194) AND  (CURRENT_DATE)
```

where `visit_date` is a string of format yyyy-mm-dd.

`CURRENT_DATE` is valid in Hive but `CURRENT_DATE-194` is giving error.

How can I do it in Hive?

Comment: use `unix_timestamp()` to compare dates

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution by using

```
visit_date BETWEEN date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,194) AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Right, unix_timestamp() is non-deterministic and prevents query from being optimized. You solution is better. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41140298/2700344

Answer (score 0):

To get data of past 194 days in `Hive`;
Try below query:

```
select * from table_1 where visit_date > date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), 194);
```

> Note: TIMESTAMP is milliseconds
>      unix_timestamp is in seconds