# Transfer big table from one Hive database to another

Tags: performance, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I would like to transfer one big (over 150 mln records and 700 columns) table from one Hive database to another, that includes a few transformations like using one **cast** on a date column, **substr** on a string column and one simple **case** statement.

So, something like this:

```
-- initial settings 
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true;
SET hive.exec.parallel=true;
SET parquet.compression=SNAPPY;
SET hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=true; 
SET hive.merge.size.per.task=1000000000;
SET hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=1000000000;

INSERT INTO databaseA.tableName PARTITION(parition_col)
CASE WHEN a='Something' THEN 'SOMETHING'
     WHEN a is null THEN 'Missing'
     ELSE a END AS a,
column1,
column2, 
...
cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS string) AS 
run_date,
substr(some_string, 1, 3)
FROM databaseB.tableName;
```

The problem is that this query is going to take a lot of time (1 mln rows per hour). Maybe anybody knows how to speed it up?

I'm using map reduce engine for this task.

Thanks!

Comment: try inserting the result to a temp table and then insert it into the main table.

Comment: Thank you @Vamsi. Now is better. Any other ideas for improvement?

Comment: In hive  there is no performance difference between loading data into a different database or the same database from which you are reading the data. A hive database usually refers to a hdfs directory. In terms of SQL I can't see how you can tune this. Performance will be decided by the size of your HDFS cluster. Have you tried running this? and what are the metrics?

Comment: The most important thing here is that this process ending up one big file (20 GB) instead of a few smaller. Also, reduce process is taking most of the time so maybe there is something with above settings? Why such a big file ended up as one big file? There is a lot of mappers and reducers during this process and reduce = 99% is taking a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

As all the data in the Hive tables are files on HDFS why don't you move/copy the files directly into the new table's HDFS location.

Example:

```
Assuming the table you want to move is already present in db1 as table_to_cpy;

create database db2;
create table db2.table_to_cpy like db1.table_to_cpy;
desc formatted db1.table_to_cpy;
--copy the hdfs table path ---> /user/hive/warehouse/db1.db/table_to_cpy

desc formatted db2.table_to_cpy;
--copy the hdfs table path ---> /user/hive/warehouse/db2.db/table_to_cpy

hadoop fs -cp /user/hive/warehouse/db1.db/table_to_cpy/* /user/hive/warehouse/db2.db/table_to_cpy/.
```

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions on how to speed-up your query:

1. Avoid unix_timestamp() if possible. This function is non-deterministic and prevents proper optimization of queries, it  will be executed in each mapper or reducer and may return different values. Use instead

   current_date() AS run_date

   See also this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41140298/2700344
2. Tune mappers and reducers parallelism. If your process ending up with one big file (20 GB) instead of a few smaller then obviously there is not enough parallelism.

For mappers, play with these settings:

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=16777216; -- 16 MB
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=1073741824; -- 1 GB
```

Decrease `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` to increase the number of reducers.

Play with these settings. Success criteria is more mappers/reducers and your map and reduce stages are running faster.

See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842117/2700344

3. Try to add `distribute by parition_col` It will distribute data between reducers according to partition keys and as a result each reducer will create less partitions and consume less memory. Also it helps to avoid too many small output files. This setting should be used with `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` to avoid problem with uneven distribution between reducers and to avoid too big output files.